# Unambiguous word for last in chronological order

Tags: single-word-requests, time

Here's the scenario, I want to list all of a customer's appointments, ending with the "last" one, regardless of whether that was in the past or scheduled for the future.  I have come up with a few words for that: last, final, latest.  The trouble is the meanings of the ones I have come up with are ambiguous.

Last and final could imply that this is the customer's last appointment ever, and they won't be coming back in the future.
Latest could mean the appointment that occurs latest in the day, or the one they showed up the latest for.

So is there a single word or short phrase (eg "most recent") that unambiguously carries the meaning of "last chronologically, for now."

Edit: Realised I was getting downvotes for not filling out all the single word request criteria so

Sample Sentence: "This fields represents the customer's ***last*** appointment.

Thesauruses:

- MW had "bottommost, closing, concluding, final, hindmost, lag, latest, latter, rearmost, terminal, terminating, ultimate" for synomyms of last.
- OED had  rear, hindmost, bringing up the rear, nearest the rear, at the end, furthest back, at the back, at the back of the queue, aftermost, endmost, furthest behind, final, ultimate, most remote, remotest, furthest, utmost, extreme

Comment: What's wrong with your own suggestion "most recent"?

Comment: That would suggest the appointment is in the past.

Comment: If you want to list all of a customer's appointments why don't you just do that with their dates? If they are listed chronologically it is obvious which is the last one and avoids the dilemma.

Comment: Chronologically most distant.  Or futurest.

Comment: "That would suggest that the appointment is in the past." But in your question you state "regardless of whether that was in the past or scheduled for the future." So, is the past allowed or not? If not, it's not clear what you're asking. If it is allowed, I don't understand your objection—assuming they have made no future appointments.

Comment: The word or phrase needs to apply equally well to something in the past or in the future. I want a word meaning "Furthest from the big bang" essentially.

Comment: Maybe "most distant" or even, "furthest"? As in, "My furthest scheduled appointment is in May"

Comment: How about "post-penultimate"?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "concluding" would serve your purpose. It usually carries the connotation that this is the last in a current set of items.

Definition snippet from [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concluding):

> 1 : END 
>   *The festivities concluded at midnight.*

Answer (score 0):

### latter

---

> denoting the second or second mentioned of two people or things.

---

> last-mentioned, second-mentioned, second of the two, second, last,
>   later

### rearmost

---

> Furthest back

### final

---

> coming at the end of a series.